# Firebase User Creation with Admin SDK - Best Practice?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have server-side rendered react application that allows users to create their own accounts. I am using the Firebase Auth **email / password** authentication method.

Firebase's client-side web sdk has a [rate limit of 100 new accounts / hour / IP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start). This seemed low for situations where many people attempting account creation may be sharing an IP (campuses, event wifi, etc.).

I have implemented a firebase cloud function that creates the accounts via the Admin SDK instead, to circumvent this limit. I have a front end form with email, password, and recaptchaV2. The cloud function validates the recaptcha response before creating the user to help curb abuse.

I am concerned that this is still not best practice, for some reason, to use the admin sdk to allow users to create their own accounts, and unknowingly am opening my app up to huge security issues. I have only inferred that the Admin SDK should just be used for administrative purposes (like if I wanted to write a script to bulk import accounts).

Is it okay to use the admin-sdk as I have set it up?

Looking for advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you create the user on the client to bypass the rate limitation? Is it because you are requiring reCAPTCHA for account creation?

Comment: The rate limit is built into the web-sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Comment: I know. That is expected. Users sign up from one device and are unlikely to hit the limit if the request is sent from the device. However, if you sending the sign up request from one server, you will hit the limit unless you use admin sdk. My question is: why not send the request from the client?

Comment: Because if you have tons of clients on the same IP address attempting to sign up, the rate limit will prevent some of them from doing so, which is a bad user experience and not viable for high-volume signups.

Comment: That is unlikely, unless you have like a classroom environment. There are some huge apps using Firebase Auth and this is not an issue for them. For the former case (shared wi-fi in conference/classroom), Firebase Auth provides a way to raise the limit manually and temporarily via Firebase Console.

Comment: The likelihood of the scenario is not the question.

Comment: As long as you are requiring a valid reCAPTCHA token before processing the request in your http cloud endpoint, you are OK to create the users via Admin SDK.